# simplify unreadable nested if/else

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, nested

I need to determine the status of a parent object based on 2 variables of each of its children. I came up with a working solution, but this includes a nested "if-else if-else". Needless to say, it doesn't look very elegant.

I was wondering if there is a way to simplify this. I have muddled around with some map/reduce code, but did not get to anything that is more elegant than the code below.

```js
const parent = {
  children: [{
      connected: true,
      online: true

    },
    {
      connected: true,
      online: true
    }
  ]
}


// all online & all connected  => connected
// all online & some connected => partially disconnected
// all online & none connected => disconnected
// some online => partially offline
// none online => offline

const onlineArr = parent.children.map(c => c.online);
const connectedArr = parent.children.map(c => c.connected);
let status;

if (!onlineArr.includes(true)) {
  status = 'Offline';
} else if (!onlineArr.includes(false)) {
  if (!connectedArr.includes(true)) {
    status = 'Disconnected';
  } else if (!connectedArr.includes(false)) {
    status = 'Connected';
  } else {
    status = 'Partially disconnected';
  }
} else {
  status = 'Partially offline';
}

console.log(status);
```

Comment: This could be a good fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @pitto, forgot that even existed. thnx!

Answer (score 0):

I'd just extract the all/some/none check into a function:

```
  const overAll = (array, key, value, /*results in */ all, some, none) =>
    array.every(it => it[key] === value) ? all : (array.some(it => it[key] === value) ? some : none);
```

Then it is as easy as:

```
 const status = (
   overAll(parent.children, "online", true, undefined, "Partially offline", "Offline") ||
   overAll(parent.children, "connected", true, "Connected", "Partially connected", "not connected")
);
```

But your if/else is already quite clean IMO :)